# method of obtaining the number of bytes

Tags: objective-c

```
NSString str = xxxxx;
[str length];
```

This code is number of characters.

I want to get number of byte.

Comment: Given the questions you are asking, I would suggest spending some quality time with the documentation.  The NSString class documentation would answer this question in short order.

Answer (score 5):

Use `-[NSString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:]`.

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` is a unicode string. Thus, there is no such thing as byte length without specifying an encoding for the unicode code points of each letter in the string. As others have pointed out, once you choose an encoding,

```
-[NSString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:]
```

is what you need.

You might find [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) what-you-need-to-know tutorial on Unicode helpful.